# How to find out the accuracy?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I've wondered if there is a function in sklearn which corresponds to the accuracy(difference between actual and predicted data) and how to print it out?

```
from sklearn import datasets 
iris = datasets.load_iris()
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
naive_classifier= GaussianNB()
y =naive_classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target).predict(iris.data)
pr=naive_classifier.predict(iris.data)
```

Comment: In your case y and pr are same, ie predicted from the classifier on same data. To find the accuracy, you should not use same data in training and predicting

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most classifiers in scikit have an inbuilt [`score()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.score) function, in which you can input your X_test and y_test and it will output the appropriate metric for that estimator. For classification estimators it is mostly `'mean accuracy'`.

Also [`sklearn.metrics`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#sklearn-metrics-metrics) have many functions available which will output different metrics like `accuracy`, `precision`, `recall` etc.

For your specific question you need [`accuracy_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score)

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
score = accuracy_score(iris.target, pr)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `accuracy_score`, find documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html).

Implement like this -

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy = accuracy_score(prediction, labels_test)
```

This will return a float value. The float value describes (number of points classified correctly) / (total number of points in your test set)

Answer (score 3):

First you need to import the metrics from sklearn and in metrics you need to import the accuracy_score
Then you can get the accuracy score

The accuracy_score formula is
**accuracy_score=correct_predictions/No of Predictions**

`from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score`
`accuracy_score(y_actual,y_predicted)`

PS. It works great for classification techniques

Answer (score 2):

You have to import `accuracy_score` from `sklearn.metrics`. It should be like below,

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print accuracy_score(predictions,test set of labels)
```

The formula for accuracy is:

Number of points classified correctly / all the points in test set

Answer (score 2):

You can use `score()` function in `GaussianNB` directly. In this way you don't need to predict labels and then calculate accuracy.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb = gnb.fit(train_data, train_labels)
score = gnb.score(test_data, test_labels)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use sklearn's metrics to get your model's accuracy you can either use `accuracy_score(test_data,predictions)` to get the difference between model's values and actual values, apart from this you can check for error rates in model `metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test,predictions)` for mean absolute errors,  `metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, predictions)` for mean squared errors. etc

Answer (score 0):

For Classification problems use "metrics.accuracy_score" and Regression use "metrics.r2_score".

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).