# Error while calculating accuracy using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i am trying to find out the accuracy of my model using below code but facing error

```
X = df.iloc[:,-1].values.reshape(-1,1)
Y = df.iloc[:,0:2].values
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = 20)
reg = LinearRegression()
model = reg.fit(X_train, Y_train)
pred = model.predict(X_test)
score = accuracy_score(pred,Y_test)
print(score)
```

error i am getting is below

> ValueError: continuous-multioutput is not supported

Sample Data

```
R&D Spend,Administration,Marketing Spend,State,Profit
165349.2,136897.8,471784.1,New York,192261.83
162597.7,151377.59,443898.53,California,191792.06
153441.51,101145.55,407934.54,Florida,191050.39
144372.41,118671.85,383199.62,New York,182901.99
```

Comment: @coldspeed I am not using GridSearchCV to avoid "recall". i guess question is not duplicate

Comment: Please show your data and/or provide a [mcve] that helps us reproduce the issue and I'll reopen.

Comment: @coldspeed updated the question with sample data

Comment: Okay, how do you think the accuracy for real valued predictions should be calculated?

Comment: @coldspeed I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471082/how-to-find-out-the-accuracy

Comment: That's for a classification problem. This is a regression problem? This is a really basic difference, and if you cannot tell then I strongly recommend doing a little reading up on the concepts.

Comment: @coldspeed i am new to ML. can you suggest how to calculate accuracy for regression ? any default API like accuracy_score

Comment: check out `mean_squared_error`. The the closer this value is to 0, the better your model* (* - your mileage may vary).

Comment: @coldspeed its giving me greater value , so i used r2_score its giving me proper score. Thanks for your inputs